# ASP.NET MVC TextArea doesn't respect row parameters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following `TextArea` which contains formatted XML:

```
@Html.TextArea("ConfigXmlView", System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Model.IdentifiFIConfiguration.ConfigXml).ToString(), 20, 50, null)
```

The row parameter (`20` in this case) seems to not affect the actual height of the text area at all. What could the problem be? And is there a way to automatically set the height of the text area to fit it's content?

Comment: Is there some CSS that's fixing the height of the textarea?

Comment: Argh... yes. Sorry, I forgot to check that. Submit your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll most likely be because the height is fixed within your CSS, so regardless of your rows the height won't alter.